# signature widget (painter) does it exists in android?

Tags: android

I want an widget that one can sign on it on the tocuh screen its ambivalent to painter so is there a way using the painter in my application?... thanx

i want it too fit the 2.1 version does it exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not exist by default,

But can be made by extending a SurfaceView (creating your own 'widget')
If you handle the touch events to draw a line on the surface with the onDraw method,
then save the drawing to a Bitmap image.

You can then add your custom widget to your layout to show your signature widget.

Real autograph recognition for authenticating logins and such is however a completely different and way more advanced topic.